# Using <input type="hidden" /> combine with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a code to iterate a list sent from Controller to View page like this:

```
<tbody>
    <th:block th:each="job,iterStat : ${listJob}">
        <tr class="job-detail" th:if="${job.status == 'success'}">
            <td th:text='${iterStat.index}+1'><input name="id"
                                    type="hidden" value="th:text='${job.id}'" /></td>
            <td th:text='${job.name}'></td>
            <td th:text='${job.time}'></td>
            <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
            <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="danger job-detail" th:if="${job.status == 'danger'}">
            <td th:text='${iterStat.index}+1'><input name="id"
                                    type="hidden" value="th:text='${job.id}'" /></td>
            <td th:text='${job.name}'></td>
            <td th:text='${job.time}'></td>
            <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
            <td>yyyy/mm/dd hh24/mi/ss</td>
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</tbody>
```

I have a hidden value in first td:

```
<td th:text='${iterStat.index}+1'><input name="id"
                                type="hidden" value="th:text='${job.id}'" /></td>
```

But when I check it the hidden value was undefined. Here is the image show that input element was not generated. I dont know what to do this issue :( Havent met it before. 
[image]

Comment: th:text replaces all content in td ( including your input )

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `th:text='${iterStat.index}+1'` overwritten the hidden input. You also might want `th:value` in the input.

If you want both, try this.

```
<td>
    <th:block th:text='${iterStat.index}+1'></th:block>
    <input name="id" type="hidden" th:value="${job.id}" />
</td>
```

Comment: So is there anyway to combine them?

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM I added a sample. will this help?

Comment: `value="th:text='${job.id}'"` doesn't seem right... Is this what you are intending? `th:text` will not run.

Comment: use th:text and the input will not hide

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM Why use `th:text` in the input? You might want `th:value`?

Comment: I find out th:value, combine with your code and it work well

Comment: I'm new to thymeleaf :D Thanks for your help

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM Good! I'll finalize my answer